# Twilio can upload in google bucket but can't download from it

Tags: google-cloud-storage, twilio-api

I have a whatsapp bot with the help of Twilio that has two main purposes :

1. ask users for a voice note which is then uploaded in a google cloud bucket
2. ask other users to transcribe the voice notes previously uploaded.

For this, I use a google service account and its JSON key so that my bot can access a GCP bucket. I run tests to assert if the bot has the "storage.objects.create/get" rights, which it does. But it can't retrieve data it previously uploaded even though it is able to upload it to the bucket, it also has storage admin rights (for testing pruposes) so I suppose the problem isn't an auth/permission issue.

When checking the logs in the twilio console, I have these two warnings :

- **11200 Twilio’s servers were unable to fetch a non-error response from the designated URL.** Twilio’s servers were unable to fetch a non-error response from the designated URL.
- **63019 Media failed to download** Media failed to download

The HTTP status is 403, which suggest an auth issue. Error Message is "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."

Am I missing something obvious ? Since the bot is able to upload, shouldn't be able to download to considering I gave it the proper rights ?

Thanks in advance for your help.